# Installing WebTrends to an iOS game made in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, cocoapods, webtrends

As it says on the tin, I made a game in Unity, and built it for iOS devices. The clients asked if we could implement WebTrends into the game, and so I followed [this link](https://help.webtrends.com/legacy/en/ios/docs/public_guides/Core-SDK---Getting-Started-Guide.html) for instructions on how to install it.

This is what my pod file looks like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/Webtrends/ios-sdk.git'

pod 'Webtrends-SDK/Core', '~>3.0'

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
    pod 'Webtrends-SDK/Core', '~> 3.0'
end
```

After running `pod install` however, this is my result:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Webtrends-SDK/Core":
  In Podfile:
    Webtrends-SDK/Core (~> 3.0)

Specs satisfying the `Webtrends-SDK/Core (~> 3.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I tried to google what the minimum deployment target is for WebTrends SDK Core 3.0, but came up with a blank.

I went back in Unity to check, and the minimum deployment target was set to 6.0. I bumped it up to 8.0, rebuilt, and re-did the cocoapods install, but I've met with the same result.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: 8.0 looks right - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/c/8/8/Webtrends-SDK/3.2.7/Webtrends-SDK.podspec.json#L14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by setting my minimum build target to 8.0 in Unity, then adding the following line to my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
```

And the pod install resulted in this:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Webtrends-SDK (3.2.7)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
```